# "background-image:url("+bg+")" , what is the + sign for ? Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

"background-image:url("+bg+")" , what is the + sign for  ? Vue.js

as title . i dont understand why there are + sign added in url() ?

```
computed:{
        content_bg(){
            return "background-image:url(" + this.poiInfo.head_pic_url + ")"
        },
```

any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: You are simply concatenating a string in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` sign is not for the url. It is being used as string concatenation operator here. It adds the second string at the end of the first string. For example `"a" + "b"` equals `"ab"`.

Your function is returning an string. If the value of `this.poiInfo.head_pic_url` is, lets says, `www.example.com/head_pic` then your function `content_bg()` will return a string value of `background-image:url(www.example.com/head_pic)`.

```
content_bg(){
    return "background-image:url(" + this.poiInfo.head_pic_url + ")"
},
```

Comment: what strings would be added with this.poiInfo.head_pic_url

Comment: `background-image:url(` will be added before the value of `this.poiInfo.head_pic_url` and `)` will be added after this.